# Windows Phone 8 Getting name of town from GPS location

Tags: windows-phone-8, gps, maps, bing-maps

I'm doing an application in windows phone 8 and I need a function which return name of  district, town district or village from GPS coordinates. It would be best if he went without connection to the internet,  from maps on phone. Thanks for your response and time.

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns the name of the village
/// </summary>
/// <param name="geoCoordinate">GPS coordinate</param>
/// <returns>returns the name of the village</returns>
string NameOfPlace(GeoCoordinate geoCoordinate)
{

}
```

Comment: There's no API for doing that offline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [ReverseGeocodingQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.maps.services.reversegeocodequery%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) to get information about your current location, but it's **not** working offline.

To get information use following lines of code:

```
string NameOfPlace = "";
ReverseGeocodeQuery MyReverseGeocodeQuery = null;

void GetNameOfPlace(GeoCoordinate geoCoordinate)
{
    MyReverseGeocodeQuery = new ReverseGeocodeQuery();
    MyReverseGeocodeQuery.GeoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(geoCoordinate.Latitude, geoCoordinate.Longitude);
    MyReverseGeocodeQuery.QueryCompleted += ReverseGeocodeQuery_QueryCompleted;
    MyReverseGeocodeQuery.QueryAsync();
}

private void ReverseGeocodeQuery_QueryCompleted(object sender, QueryCompletedEventArgs<IList<MapLocation>> e)
{
    var result = e.Result[0];
    NameOfPlace  = result.Information.Address.Street + " " + result.Information.Address.City + " " + result.Information.Address.Country;
}
```

Result for GeoCoordinate 48.774010, 9.224396 would be *Zur Staibhöhe Stuttgart Germany*.

Btw.: The localization of the phone is being used (If the language is german, the result would be *Zur Staibhöhe Stuttgart Deutschland*)